# How to store redshift credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm creating an application which needs to create schemas/tables on amazon Redshift. 
In order to do this I must run these actions with a privileged user. 
I'm not sure where to store its credentials. 
I know that for other AWA actions, like S3,  I can call the Metadata service and get temp credentials, and it looks like there is such a thing for copy command:

```
copy table_name
from 's3://objectpath'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=<temporary-access-key-id>;aws_secret_access_key=<temporary-secret-access-key>;token=<temporary-token>';
```

but I haven't find such a thing for other commands.
I was thinking about storing the credentials in an encrypted S3 file. 
Is this the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

We are using environment variables on EC2 instances to store credentials for Redshift. Code is deployed to the EC2's via Elastic Beanstalk where the enviroment variables are easily managed.

The EC2 machines run Python scripts to perform COPY commands and SQL queries to transform the data from there.

Comment: Is it more secured to use environment variables?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using psql to run sql scripts, you can use a .pgpass file (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/libpq-pgpass.html).  The credentials are not encrypted, but the file permissions are locked down to 600, only readable by the script owner.

Comment: I've just read that there is such a thing called profile for Credentials, which Amazon recommends. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/net-dg-config-creds.html
I'll will give it a try